# Call Bitbucket REST API using 2leg oauth token

Tags: php, oauth, bitbucket

I am trying to call bitbucket's api using 2-legged oauth authentication.

I call

```
https://bitbucket.org/!api/1.0/oauth/request_token
```

with my oauth secret and key and get the following:

```
oauth_token_secret=<token_secret>&oauth_token=<token>&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

How can I use this to call an api function, such as

```
https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/user
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you have received accesstoken & secret, when you send the request add a (Authorization) Header as,

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="<YourKey>",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="<TIMESTAMP>",oauth_nonce="2694561796",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="<Signature>"
```

where,

TIMESTAMP= current epoch (ms)
oauth_nonce random number

**Important thing is oauth_signature**

Read through here on how to generate,

[Oauth 1.0 Signature](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4)

Signature has to be precalculated before sending the request. And this will do it.

To test it you can tryout it here, [Apigee Bitbucket API Console](http://restbrowser.bitbucket.org/)

PS: Its weird that Bit Bucket uses OAuth 1.0, well known for its vulnerabilities.

[Session Fixation Attack](http://hueniverse.com/2009/04/explaining-the-oauth-session-fixation-attack/)