# how to use access token to authenticate user after login through twitter in node.js passport

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, access-token, passport.js

I need to build a token based authentication on my node.js app , that the user can use the his facebook or twitter credential to login my app, and use access token to get to resource. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397052/nodejs-passport-authentication-token) is suggesting to **once authenticated through facebook or twitter or other, use access token on every request, and Session is NOT needed at all**
**For example**

GET /api/v1/somefunction?token='abcedf'

1. The client gets the access token from the response.
2. The client calls some server api with the token argument.

so the following code, is to authorize user through twitter, if my app doesn't find my user information, then store user information into the database.

```
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
      consumerKey: config.twitter.clientID,
      consumerSecret: config.twitter.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: config.twitter.callbackURL
    },
    function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
        console.log('TwitterStrategy   /auth/twitter.............',profile.id, profile.displayName, profile.username, profile.emails[0], profile._json.avatar_url);   
        userModel.findUserByQuery({ 'social.twitter.id': profile.id }, function (err, user) {
          if (!user) {
            console.log('twitter user not found'.red);
            userModel.createNewUser( {  username:profile.username,  
                                        email:profile.emails[0].value, 
                                        img:profile._json.avatar_url, 
                                        fullname:profile.displayName,
                                        password:profile._json.avatar_url,
                                        social:{twitter:{id:profile.id,avatar:profile._json.avatar_url, name:profile.username,token:accessToken} }}, 
            function(err,data){
                if(err) return done(err);
                else if(!data)  return done(null, false, { message: 'can not create your profile in database' });           
                else {
                   console.log('save the new twitter user into database'.green, data._id);
                   return done(err, user);
                }               
            })          
        } else {
          console.log('twitter user  found'.green);
          return done(err, user);
        }
      })                
    }
))
```

However, I have two questions,

**1.** how to send the access token to the client for the following requests

in the code, after authenticated from twitter, I get the access token and send this token to the client on the browser, since the token is embedded in the url parameter, I tried the code
res.redirect ('/users/profile ? token = blabla '), but in the client browser, the url is still shown as '/users/profile' rather than '/users/profile ? token=blabla'

**2.** once authenticated from twitter, the following request with token is going through my app locally( which I store the token in database, and compare the following token to verify) or still to twitter API to authenticate?

if in the first situation, so I should store the token into the database, in order to compare the following request in token in the following requests to my app? is that right

Answer (score 2):

I'm also trying hard to get this, and just found this rather relevant answer: [Call Bitbucket REST API using 2leg oauth token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559351/call-bitbucket-rest-api-using-2leg-oauth-token)

I just can't get how to do this with passport? Particularly, how to get ouath instance from passport authenticated session, to do oauth.get(...), as described here: https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth

UPDATE: Jared (author of passportjs) has explained this is wrong approach in the google groups thread below, and recommends to use https://github.com/mikeal/request.

This is how it works for me:

```
var oauth = {
  consumer_key: process.env.BB_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.BB_CONSUMER_SECRET
};

passport.use(new BitbucketStrategy({
  ...
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    oauth = extend(oauth, {
      token: token,
      token_secret: tokenSecret
  });
}
```

Note, tokens above may need be persisted per user in clustered environment.

Later, to access api, do:

```
request.get({url: 'protected end point', oauth: oauth})
```

Hope it will help someone!

Comment: See also [What's the correct way to use PassportJS to access the Yahoo Contact API?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/passportjs/FCG-St-ETFs)

Comment: Gist: https://gist.github.com/avalez/7722698 Bitbucket OAuth consumer example (nodejs w. passport)